# Change the Color of Marker Option in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

In my code i am using this sort of code to make a marker option when clicking in a marker .

```
MarkerOptions op = new MarkerOptions();
                    op.position(point)
                            .title(Location_ArrayList.get(j).getCity_name())
                            .snippet(Location_ArrayList.get(j).getVenue_name())
                            .draggable(true);

                    icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .fromResource(R.drawable.pin);
```

[image]

I want to change background color of the marker option and make it to black . How to change it programmatically here.

Comment: it's not possible. but as per my opinion set up `Custom Info Window` and change root layout background

Answer (score 0):

Use the Icon Factory, as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#customize_the_marker_color). Just add this to your MarkerOptions.

```
MarkerOptions op = new MarkerOptions();
 op.position(point)
             .title(Location_ArrayList.get(j).getCity_name())
             .snippet(Location_ArrayList.get(j).getVenue_name())
             .draggable(true)
             .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
```

Make sure that you then create the Marker with the options:

```
Marker marker=new Marker(op);
```

Comment: op.position(point)
       .title(Location_ArrayList.get(j).getCity_name())
       .snippet(Location_ArrayList.get(j).getVenue_name())
       .draggable(true)
       .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));

Comment: Did you use the options to create the Marker after setting them?

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
 Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.position(MELBOURNE)
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
```

Comment: I have tried this but nothing happens..............op.position(point)
       .title(Location_ArrayList.get(j).getCity_name())
       .snippet(Location_ArrayList.get(j).getVenue_name())
       .draggable(true)
       .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));

Answer (score 0):

its long overdue but may help someone else looking for this ...
You cannot just change the color, what you need to do is use the GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter to show the text instead of the more simple title and snippet approach.
You need to override the adapter and set it in your map.
myMapObject.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MyMarkerInfoWindowAdapter());

see in here:
http://www.rogcg.com/blog/2014/04/20/android-working-with-google-maps-v2-and-custom-markers